# $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n^\alpha}$, with $a>0$, $\alpha$ is a real number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

After some calculations I found that the limit of this series is $a$.

Then, I've learnt that if $a$ is in $(0,1)$ the series is convergent and if it is in $(1, +\infty)$ it is divergent and I don't really understand why.

Can anybody explain this to me?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155794/comparison-test-about-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-fracannb

Comment: Simple application of Ratio Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: When $a>1$, then $\frac{a^n}{n^\alpha} \to \infty$, which contradicts with necessary condition convergence of the series.

Comment: Then why did I have to calculate its limit first? That's why I don't understand.

Comment: @Octavian Niculescu. Added explanation. Feel free to ask more if/when you'll need.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. Thanks :)